# LSTM layer does not accept the input shape of CNN layer output

Tags: python, lstm, sequential, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a CNN + LSTM network, but the LSTM layer is not accepting the input shape. Is there anything I can do?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, (2,2), padding = 'same', input_shape=(30, 216, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (2,2), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(512, input_shape = (7, 54, 256,)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
```

ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_21 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 7, 54, 256]

Comment: You can simply adopt a reshape operation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63789979/10375049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LSTM](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) layer in Keras expects this format as input:

```
inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].
```

For this reason, you can't pass non-recurrent layers directly. First, `Flatten()` the layer before, and wrap that layer into a `TimeDistributed` layer, like this:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(8))
```

This [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/time_distributed/) layer *allows to apply a layer to every temporal slice of an input*. Here's a fully working example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, LSTM, \
    Dense, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, Activation, TimeDistributed
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(100, 30, 216, 1)
y = np.random.randint(0, 7, 100)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (2,2), padding = 'same', input_shape=(30, 216, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (2,2), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(8))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Nicolas. Even though, using your code, it doesn't throw an error  anymore, the notebooks (both Jupyter and google collab) crash on the first epoch before the 4th batch. I tried already changing the number of layers and parameters as well as drastically decreasing the train and test data. GPU usage stands at 60% and CPU at 30%, so I doubt the issue can be found there. To give you a bit more of a background,  I am trying to do speech emotion classification based on the NN architecture of the paper "Speech emotion recognition using deep 1D & 2D CNN LSTM networks".

Comment: Yes probably because you put an enormous amount of neurons. However that's a different issue. If the issue you posted about is solved you should mark it as such